# Ignore Linux executables with hgignore

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to set up .hgignore correctly, but I'm having some problems. I don't want to see executables in my list of unadded files.

On Windows, this is very easy: `*.exe`. On Linux, executables typically do not have an extension. So how do you set up a filter that will ignore files that have no extension?

Comment: `syntax: regexp    ^[^\.]+$`

Should ignore files that don't have dots in the name, but this will also ignore directories -- typically you'd have the executables in some directory and you'd put the directory in `.hgignore`

Comment: @isbadawi: I don't really have much choice over where executables get put, so that's not an option. Sorry.

Comment: Linux executable can have **any** name

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no way to do it.  You could, relatively easily, build a list of the executable files that exist now and automatically add them to  your .hgignore but new ones will still show up as un-tracked.

Answer (score 1):

I have occasionally tweaked my project build files (Makefiles, .sconstructs, etc.) to build UNIX executables as foo.x rather than foo, just to make automatically ignoring them easier.